# Run Functions on Multiple Columns of Multiple Data Frames

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have the following data frames:

```
a = sample(letters[1:10])
b = sample(1:1000000, 10)
c = sample(1:100000000, 10)

d = sample(letters[1:26], 10)
e = sample(1:1000000, 10)
f = sample(1:100000000, 10)

g = sample(letters[1:26], 10)
h = sample(1:1000000, 10)
i = sample(1:100000000, 10)

data = data.frame(a,b,c)
data2 = data.frame(d,e,f)
data3 = data.frame(g,h,i)




 data
              Col1   Col2     Col3
        1     a 626275 52114901
        2     j  26543 70683919
        3     c   8953   284605
        4     h 822415 35245405
        5     f 595095 81093354
        6     i 812429 71119567
        7     g 100678 87776459
        8     e  54772  9709717
        9     d  19375 43611618
        10    b 174711  7254034

data2
   Col1   Col2     Col3
1     y  12495 78654339
2     p 423945 79628767
3     k 378461 36729002
4     x 795469 98196961
5     h 240119 71903172
6     v 691621 74276314
7     d 702074 64715230
8     n 718401 21247081
9     s 580166 52888162
10    b 194630 92287079

data3
   Col1   Col2     Col3
1     m 391166 98761754
2     v 321615 71765127
3     g 959452 80114937
4     w 380126 25877104
5     f 655875 69610059
6     s 267364  7113484
7     h 391116  6801473
8     i 663616 73956544
9     o 936505 94244449
10    c 514173 82174024
```

I also have a table with all of the contents of column `Col1` (this table is called table `k`. What I would like to do is write a function that allows me to subset the contents of the data frames by identifying all of the items in `Col1` and table `k` as a match.

Table K:

```
k
   Col1
1     a
2     j
3     c
4     h
5     f
6     i
7     g
8     e
9     d
10    b
11    y
12    p
13    k
14    x
15    h
16    v
17    d
18    n
19    s
20    b
21    m
22    v
23    g
24    w
25    f
26    s
27    h
28    i
29    o
30    c
```

I then want to only print the contents of column `Col2` as an output of the function. Since I have multiple data frames, I know I have to put them in a list and then use lapply once I create the function. I have gotten this far, but my code does not work.

```
get_tair = function(df, col1, col2){
  df[df[[col1]] %in% k$$Col1,]
  print(df[[col2]])
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I used that as an example. The real dataset I am using has some values missing in each data frame so all of the values wouldn't be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can place the 'data' objects in a `list` and use `lapply`

```
out_lst <- lapply(list(data, data2, data3), 
     function(dat) get_tair(dat, col1 = 'Col1', col2 = 'Col2'))
```

-function used

```
get_tair = function(df, col1, col2){
   df[df[[col1]] %in% k$Col1,]

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` :

```
get_tair = function(df, col){
  unique(merge(df, k, by.x = col, by.y = 'Col1'))
}

list_data <- list(data, data2, data3)
lapply(list_data, function(x) get_tair(x, names(x)[1]))
```

Note that the sample data generated for 3 dataframes has different columns than what you have shown. (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`).